# How to layout UITableViewCell according to size of the label inside?

Tags: ios, layout, uitableview

[image]

As you see in the photo, there are two labels 1 foursquare icon and 1 profile photo. First label is not resizing dynamically. And second is not aligned correctly.

What can I do to resolve this? What is common pattern for that?

[image: Updated image]

Now I have another problem with the view in the middle. It is not going down when the title becomes bigger. Any solutions?

UPDATE: I solved it in layoutSubviews as you said. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the height of the tableview cell dynamically with some kind of method.

Personally I use  twitter for similar tableview format, simply just Create cell .h .m for your custom cells,

you can find original example [on github](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/TwitterFeed)

***Especially look at the `(void)layoutSubviews` code below***

Look at this [tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/09/23/uitableviewcell-dynamic-height/) as well

yourcustomcell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TwitterFeedCell : UITableViewCell {}
@end
```

your custom cell.m

```
   #import "TwitterFeedCell.h"
    #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    @implementation TwitterFeedCell

    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) {
            [[self detailTextLabel] setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            [[self detailTextLabel] setNumberOfLines:NSIntegerMax];

            [[[self imageView] layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
            [[[self imageView] layer] setCornerRadius:5.0];

            //[self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        }
        return self;
    }
    - (void)layoutSubviews {
        [super layoutSubviews];

        CGRect rect = [[self imageView] frame];
        rect.origin.x = 5.0;
        rect.origin.y = 5.0;
        [[self imageView] setFrame:rect];

        rect = [[self textLabel] frame];
        rect.origin.x = 60.0;
        rect.origin.y = 5.0;
        [[self textLabel] setFrame:rect];

        rect = [[self detailTextLabel] frame];
        rect.origin.x = 60.0;
        rect.origin.y = 27.0;
        [[self detailTextLabel] setFrame:rect];
    }
    @end
```

call your custom cell class on your cell identifier

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tweets";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[TwitterFeedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        //cell = [[TwitterFeedCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //cell.textLabel.text
    //cell.detailTextLabel.text
    //cell.imageView.image
}
```

Comment: But origin.y of detailTextLabel should be changed according to the size of the textLabel. How can it be handled?

Comment: in my answer you cant handle it. you need to set your `cell.textLabel.text=Username + said;` then your `detail.textlabel.text=the feed from user`. See the image that is exactly the above code you may need to modify it little bit. http://s3.amazonaws.com/cocoacontrols_production/ios_screens/237/full.png?1306257816

Answer (score 1):

use this method to calculate height and width of string

```
+  (CGSize) calculateLabelHeightWith:(CGFloat)width text:(NSString*)textString
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(width, 9999);
    CGSize size = [textString sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:14]
                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}

+ (CGSize) calculateLabelWidthOfString:(NSString*)textString withFont:(UIFont*)font
{
    CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(9999, 22);
    CGSize size = [textString sizeWithFont:font
                         constrainedToSize:maximumSize 
                             lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}
```

But still you will have to set height dynamically of table view cell

for that

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return <height>;
}
```